# Mark heading done when all checkboxes are checked

Tags: org-mode

I want to mark heading done when all items in the checklist are checked.
In this example :

```
* TODO Heading [2/3]
  - [X] Stuff 1
  - [ ] Stuff 2
  - [X] Stuff 3
```

When toggling Stuff 2 (`C-c C-c`) I want to switch the heading to DONE automatically.
Is there any org function to check if all nested checkboxes are checked?

Comment: This is a [FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#mark-done-when-all-checkboxes-checked).

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me!